# How many joints/ bones were used to animate the Sorting Hat?

Tags: harry-potter, behind-the-scenes, sorting-hat

While watching [this clip of Harry wearing the Sorting Hat](https://youtu.be/z4K2F_OALPQ), I understood that the Sorting Hat has a lot of fidelity in the animation of its mimic and can even gesture.

With Google, I did not find any information on its construction.

Is there any information or analysis which says how many [joints/bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation) are needed for that?

Obviously it needs much more than these cheap 5-servo Sorting Hats have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sorting hat was largely CGI. There seems to have also been a puppet hat, but it was operated as a hand-puppet (with the operator simply obstructed by the person wearing it or digitally painted out) and as far as I can tell, there was never an animatronic hat.

> But the Hogwarts Sorting Hat was mainly a creation of CG crews. *"We gave the animator first crack at designing it,"* says [Production designer Stuart] Craig. *"It's really quite ingenious, the way that the eyes and mouth are just parts of its folds."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Entertainment Weekly: 23 Astounding Harry Potter Slides](https://ew.com/gallery/harry-potter-23-astounding-props/?slide=351524#351524)</sup></sub>

We also have a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/1oeayp/my_father_worked_at_ilm_doing_special_effects_for/) from Reddit User [noramacsbicth](https://www.reddit.com/user/noramacsbitch/) (AKA Nora Koonce, daughter of Russell Koonce, Digital Effects Artist for the various potter films) in which she described the hat thusly;

> I got to wear the ACTUAL sorting hat. Depressingly enough, **it was just a plain brown hat shaped vaguely like the sorting hat- most of it was done completely with visual effects.**

---

You can see an earlier version of the hand-puppet [here](https://www.icollector.com/HARRY-POTTER-ORIGINAL-SORTING-HAT-PUPPET-SKIN_i17176822). This one never made it into the film

[image]

---

As to the joints on the CGI model, it's probably instructive to look at the [CGI puppet for Dobby](https://youtu.be/Q8KiJNoYB9o?t=302) (animated by the same studio that animated the hat). As you can see there are *thousands* of potential points of articulation rather than a singular skeleton inside the model. Each point can be deformed by the animators to give the effect of movement. There's no good reason to assume that they used a different technique for the hat.

[image]

Comment: I am aware that most was done with CGI, but also this had to be animated (in software).

Comment: Apologies for the non-English translation on the making-of. I can't seem to find and English-speaking version.

Comment: @TorstenKnodt not all computer animation is skeletal animation. In 2002 the most prominent facial animation tech would be [morph target animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation) (also used to animate Gollum's face in LotR movies, in conjunction with motion capture). This technique does not require a skeleton structure, and Dobby model shown in linked video seems to use the same approach.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov - The sorting hat in later films explicitly didn't use motion capture. It was hand-animated using 'keyframe technology'. I'm not sure about the earlier films though, so I've excluded that from the answer.